# На Mете раньше тоже можно было предлагать правки? А если нет, то это баг?

Tags: поддержка, правки, знаки, мета, предлагаемые-правки

На Мете раньше тоже можно было предлагать правки? А если нет, то это баг?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кажется речь идёт о правках описаний меток:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Есть даже один человек, проверивший на Мете больше 100 правок. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/73/proofreader

Answer (score 2):

- Можно предлагать описания меток (см. соседний ответ).
- **Участники, репутация которых меньше 100, могут предлагать правки общих сообщений.**