# Переписываем статью справки про политику, связанную с ответами от ИИ!

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, справка, генеративный-ии

Год назад в наш справочный центр была добавлена статья [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247/532877). Но на данный момент она частично устарела, к тому же она очень сжата и не везде ясна. Поэтому предлагаю её переписать, как раз сейчас в блоке <kbd>важное</kbd> висит [тема про баннер о запрете ИИ-ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13138/532877), который будет ссылаться на эту статью.

### Что не так

Вот текущая версия:

> ## Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?
>
> Одна из причин доверия людей к ответам на Stack Overflow в том, что все
> публикуемое содержимое проходит рецензирование сообществом, а авторы ответов обладают реальными знаниям, необходимыми для уточнения и улучшения ответов при необходимости и поддержания их в актуальном состоянии в будущем. Тексты, созданные с помощью GPT и Chat GPT, не соответствуют данным критериям, как и стандартам качества Stack Overflow в общем, а также нарушает [правила указания авторства материалов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), созданных другими людьми.
> Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от публикации сгенерированных текстов на сайте. Если вы увидите содержимое, опубликованное другими участниками, которое, вероятно, сгенерировано, сообщите об этом модераторам с помощью сигнала тревоги.

По пунктам:

1. > ## Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?

Заголовок уже устарел. Сейчас много всяких нейросеток. Мы же не только chatGPT запрещаем, а вообще все его аналоги. Для сравнения на enSO более общий:

> ## Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?

2. > Одна из причин доверия людей к ответам на Stack Overflow в том, что все публикуемое содержимое проходит рецензирование сообществом, а авторы ответов обладают реальными знаниям, необходимыми для уточнения и улучшения ответов при необходимости и поддержания их в актуальном состоянии в будущем.

Это хорошо как введение. Но к сожалению, кроме этого в статье почти ничего нет.

3. > Тексты, созданные с помощью GPT и Chat GPT, не соответствуют данным критериям, как и стандартам качества Stack Overflow в общем, а также нарушает [правила указания авторства материалов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), созданных другими людьми.

Опять таки, имена конкретных нейросеток надо заменить на ИИ в общем. К тому же, всё очень скомкано и сжато. Хотелось бы поподробней про "стандарты качества". Ну и даже в той же статье у заморских коллег побольше причин, почему ответы от ИИ плохи. Кое-какие идеи можно взять с обсуждения на нашей мете. И [ссылка на него](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247/532877) в статье тоже бы не помешала.

4. > Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от публикации сгенерированных текстов на сайте. Если вы увидите содержимое, опубликованное другими участниками, которое, вероятно, сгенерировано, сообщите об этом модераторам с помощью сигнала тревоги.

Слишком мягко написано, как мне кажется.

### Что будет включено в новую версию?

В новой версии:

- будут исправлена все проблемы, которые я описал выше.
- будут добавлены ссылки на нашу справку и мету.
- будет просто больше информации.

### Откуда будет взята информация для новой версии статьи?

- Это будет *частичный* перевод статьи с enSO.
- Кое-что будет взято из старой статьи.
- Так же будет использоваться обсуждение на нашей мете.

**P.S**: ответ на этот пост с новой версией статьи будет сделан общим, поэтому для редактирования нужно всего 100 баллов репутации. Улучшайте, если хотите!

Comment: GPT - Generative Pre-trained Transformer, что в этой аббревиатуре конкретного? Это совершенно нарицательный термин, означающий разновидность нейросети.

Comment: @aepot, "разновидность нейросети" это ещё не все нейросети, а запрещать надо все.

Comment: В английской версии ещё и ссылку изменили (`gpt-policy` → `ai-policy`) и даже редирект не поставили, бяки такие

Answer (score 3):

## Почему публикация ответов, которые были созданы искусственным интеллектом (например, chatGPT), недопустима?

Ответы, которые были сгенерированы искусственным интеллектом, запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском. Ваши сообщения на сайте должны быть либо вашей собственной работой, либо [правильно цитируемой работой других](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). В случае, если будет установлено, что вы использовали инструменты ИИ для публикации ответов, то все ваши ответы, написанные ИИ, будут [удалены](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), а репутация, полученная за них, отменится. Повторное нарушение может повлечь предупреждение модератора или даже [временную блокировку учётной записи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6703/532877).

#### Что считается «ответом, сгенерированным искусственным интеллектом»?

Ответ, сгенерированный искусственным интеллектом, — любой ответ, который полностью или частично создан с помощью интеллектуальной системы, которая автоматически создаёт развёрнутый ответ на заданный вопрос. Примеры таких инструментов:

- ChatGPT
- Bing Chat
- YandexGPT
- Bard (LaMDA)
- LLaMA

Использование любого из этих инструментов или других, им подобных, для генерации ответов запрещено.

#### Почему публикация ответов от искусственного интеллекта запрещается?

- Такие ответы *выглядят* правильными, но на самом деле могут быть неверными. Обнаружение ошибок в них затруднено тем, что в таких ответах очень много лишних слов.
- Искусственный интеллект не умеет [правильно ссылаться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) на материалы, которые были использованы для генерации ответа.
- Даже если ответ решает проблему, которая описана в вопросе, он может не учитывать важные детали (например безопасность и производительность приложения) и наоборот обращать внимание на мелочи, засоряя ответ ненужными словами.
- В конце концов, если автора вопроса устраивает ответ от ИИ, то он может спросить его напрямую.

Так же рекомендуем обратить внимание на [обсуждение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247/532877), связанное с запретом публикации ответов, сгенерированных искусственным интеллектом.

Comment: Ну, пара замечаний есть. Во-первых, в последнем предложении первого абзаца пропущена часть "lead to a warning from moderators" (так и было предусмотрено?).  Во-вторых, "что такое 'ответ, сгенерированный...'" я бы заменил на "что считается ответом, сгенерированным...". Так точнее, по-моему. В третьих, лишнее "но"  (и слово "неважные" тоже режет) во втором пункте причин. Еще, если я не путаю, не нужна запятая в обороте "им подобных".

Comment: А какой смысл дублировать Markdown, если посмотреть исходник поста может кто угодно даже без регистрации?

Comment: И все же, кто и каким образом будет делать заключение, что текст создан ИИ? (особенно в случае "частично" и "с помощью". **Как провести границу?**)

Comment: @andreymal убрал. Но на самом деле на мете нельзя без регистрации просмотреть исходники :)

Comment: @Зонтик [Редакции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/13141/revisions) → [Источник](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4c4055a5-7db9-448b-99e3-e0b5b28de9f9/view-source)

Comment: @andreymal, извиняюсь, если что-то путаю, но исходники поста можно ведь смотреть только на странице правки, а чтобы перейти на страницу правки нужно иметь достаточно репы. В данном случае — 100. Разве не так?

Comment: @Глеб ссылка «изменен 20 часов назад» доступна всем (правда, если правок не было, то и ссылки этой тоже не будет, но это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: @Глеб на мете можно предлагать правки общих сообщений: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13021/532877